# "Lock-free" one-shot event manager

Tags: c#, thread-safety, event-handling

Giving a review to [Oachkatzl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207494/threadsafe-oneshot-event-which-fires-on-subscription-if-the-event-was-fired-in-t) and recently about some other synchronization problems (Lazy with invalidate and some node-locking list), I wanted to test my skills and redesign it in most light-weight way I can muster.

I am especially concerned about thread-safety here, because there is NO LOCK statement, only [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange#System_Threading_Interlocked_CompareExchange__1___0____0___0_) in a loop, that is used for [event fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22534723/1722660) anyway. There is only one field - `object _state` to prevent torn-down reads (e.g. by overwriting sender+args without proper lock and knowing for sure we won to do the invoke).

Having single field also makes me consider changing this all to `struct`, because it will be used as private field for public event anyway.

Last thing I was thinking about was to maybe remove the runtime-typechecks (`state is Invoked`), but do not think it is worth it (would probably need wrapping the delegates in another class and using interface or common base class).

```
/// <summary>
/// Thread-safe event manager that ensures that subscribers get notified once after the event happens,
/// even if the event already happened.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="Sender">Sender of the event</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="Args">Additional arguments passed to subscribers</typeparam>
public class OneShotEvent<Sender, Args>
{
    public delegate void Handler(Sender sender, Args args);

    // helper class to store sender and args when invoked
    private class Invoked
    {
        public Sender sender;
        public Args args;
        public Invoked(Sender sender, Args args)
        {
            this.sender = sender;
            this.args = args;
        }
    }

    // Delegate (subscribers) or Invoked (sender and args)
    private object _state;

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribers will be notified once after the event happens,
    /// can be notified immediately if the event already happened.
    /// </summary>
    public event Handler Event
    {
        add
        {
            var state = _state;
            object prev;
            do
            {
                if (state is Invoked invoked)
                {
                    value(invoked.sender, invoked.args);
                    return;
                }
                prev = state;
                state = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _state, Delegate.Combine((Delegate)state, value), prev);
            }
            while (prev != state);
        }
        remove
        {
            var state = _state;
            object prev;
            do
            {
                if (state is Invoked)
                    return;
                prev = state;
                state = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _state, Delegate.Remove((Delegate)state, value), prev);
            }
            while (prev != state);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notify subscribers if not already done.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender of the notification</param>
    /// <param name="args">Arguments of the notification</param>
    /// <returns>true if no invoke was called before, false if already invoked</returns>
    public bool TryInvoke(Sender sender, Args args)
    {
        var state = _state;
        if (state is Invoked)
            return false;

        var invoked = new Invoked(sender, args);
        object prev;
        do
        {
            prev = state;
            state = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _state, invoked, prev);
            if (state is Invoked)
                return false;
        }
        while (prev != state);

        ((Handler)state)?.Invoke(sender, args);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional info can be found [in this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86095/discussion-between-firda-and-oachkatzl) (me and oachkatzl talking about the fragility of these lock-less solutions, how seemingly innocent modification involving double-read can destroy the correctnes of the code).

Comment: **USAGE:** This is primarily designed for events like **connection closed** or **object removed/disposed**. You can get such object from e.g. concurrent collection and it could already be closed/removed/disposed at the time you wish to subscribe to the event. This ensures correctnes (and saves you some checks) in these scenairos.